# Import of Svelte library not working in online editors but locally

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm kinda confused how to properly export my own JS library *(for Svelte)*.
When I import the library on a local project ([example local project](https://github.com/DanielSharkov/svelte-router-examples)) then everything works just fine, but when I import it in a online editor like Svelte REPL or CodeSandbox it just won't work, because the module can't be found.

The file that exports: https://github.com/DanielSharkov/svelte-router/blob/master/src/index.js

Replication on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-morning-5o7xr?file=/router.js

To replicate it on [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl) *(I can't safe to share it, because of the error)*:

```html
<script>
    import {SvelteRouter} from '@danielsharkov/svelte-router'
    console.log(SvelteRouter)
</script>
```

For more details of the library you may inspect the repository: https://github.com/DanielSharkov/svelte-router

The files `src/router.js` and `src/router.mjs` aren't in the repository, as these are builds of `index.ts`.

Comment: There are limitations/shortcomings with online editors currently, in some situations they aren't quite able to do anything a real local dev environment with configured packages is able to do. This isn't a real answer, but it may help you to know that this isn't necessarily related to you doing something wrong.

Comment: It's a mess... I've tried so many export solutions and each was either not working in online editors or local projects. Also I got strange errors in the online editors I have never faced before. So well, maybe it's really not me doing something wrong here.